# Create overlapping blocks/place blocks side by side via CSS. (Drupal)

Tags: html, css, drupal

A greenhorn(2 months) in the website field, hence not sure if this can be done in CSS, couldn't find anything on google for almost a week already, hence thought I try my luck here.

What I am attempting to do is a block of image, and another block appear on the side, overlapping the block with image.

An example will be: http://aperia.com.sg/

However, I only want like one block to appear to each of the block with images, and not so many like aperia website as shown. Of course, the website appears to be a static HTML site running scripts (correct me if I am wrong). Can this or something similar be done via CSS? (no need for animation,  just an overlap will do. )

Any hints, code examples or even links to website with tutorials to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adapt the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of your element. See also the note on the linked site:

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

An example can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_z-index&preval=2).